# Why did Mrs. Baker slap Doughboy, not Ricky and why did she ignore Doughboy when he asked her why she hit him?

Tags: plot-explanation, boyz-n-the-hood

In [**Boyz n the Hood** (1991)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101507/), when Ricky and Doughboy are fighting and when Mrs. Baker comes out to break the fight, why did she hit Doughboy, not Ricky and when Doughboy asked why she hit him, why did she ignore him?

Answer (score 1):

Ricky was "The Golden Child".  He was the future, he had the skill to become a professional football player, he was on a straight path.  Doughboy had been in jail, he was going nowhere.  It was pretty clear that Ricky was the favorite son, and with good reason.  Why would their mom slap her favorite son, when it was easy to blame everything, including the fight, on Doughboy?

Comment: But what I'm saying is "Why did she IGNORE him when he asked her why she hit him?"

Comment: Because her entire focus was on Ricky.  Doughboy wasn't worth her attention.